# Dealing with duplicates in lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I uploaded a a csv file using DictReader so I essentially have a list of dictionaries.  For example I have a called reader with the following:

```
[{'name': 'Jack', 'hits:' :7, 'misses:': 12, 'year': 10}, 
{'name': 'Lisa', 'hits': 5, 'misses': 3,' year': 8},
{'name': 'Jack', 'hits': 5, 'misses ':7, 'year': 9}]
```

I am using a loop to create lists like the following:

```
name = []
hits = []
for row in reader:
  name.append(row["name"])
  hits.append(row["hits"])
```

However I don't want duplicates in my list so where there is a duplicate name I am only interested in the names with the highest year.  So basically I want to end up with the following

```
name = [Jack, Lisa]
hits = [7,5]
```

What is the best way to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
reader = sorted(reader, key = lambda i: i['year'], reverse=True)
name = []
hits = []
for row in reader:
    if row['name'] in name:
        continue
    name.append(row["name"])
    hits.append(row["hits"])
```

Idea is to sort the `list of dict` based on `year` and then iterate over the list.

Comment: This is close, however the list of hits contains all the values.  So doesn't remove the values where name is duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'name': 'Jack', 'hits' :7, 'misses': 12, 'year': 10}, 
{'name': 'Lisa', 'hits': 5, 'misses': 3,'year': 8},
{'name': 'Jack', 'hits': 5, 'misses':7, 'year': 9}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values(by=['name','year'],ascending=False).groupby('name').first()
dict(zip(df.index,df['hits']))
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure Python (no libraries):

```
people = {}  # maps "name" -> "info"

for record in csv_reader:

    # do we have someone with that name already?
    old_record = people.get(record['name'], {})

    # what's their year (defaulting to -1)
    old_year = old_record.get('year', -1)

    # if this record is more up to date
    if record['year'] > old_year:
        # replace the old record
        people[record['name']] = record

# -- then, you can pull out your name and year lists

name = list(people.keys())
year = list(r['year'] for r in people.values())
```

If you want to learn Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('yourdata.csv')
df.groupby(['name']).max()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution without pandas:

```py
lst = [
    {"name": "Jack", "hits": 7, "misses:": 12, "year": 10},
    {"name": "Lisa", "hits": 5, "misses": 3, " year": 8},
    {"name": "Jack", "hits": 5, "misses ": 7, "year": 9},
]

out = {}
for d in lst:
    out.setdefault(d["name"], []).append(d)

name = [*out]
hits = [max(i["hits"] for i in v) for v in out.values()]

print(name)
print(hits)
```

Prints:

```py
['Jack', 'Lisa']
[7, 5]
```